# Splitting fields for $x^3-3$ and $x^5-1$

Tags: proof-verification, polynomials, field-theory, galois-theory, extension-field

I'm looking for the splitting fields of

(a) $x^3-3$

(b) $x^5-1$.

---

EDIT:

(a) Thanks to all the hints and suggestions, the three roots are

$x_1=3^{\frac{1}{3}}$, $x_2=e^{\frac{2 \pi i}{3}}3^{\frac{1}{3}}$, $x_3=e^{\frac{4 \pi i}{3}}3^{\frac{1}{3}}$

Now, the question doesn't specify the field over which these polynomials are defined, I'll take a guess and say $Q$. Now, all the roots can be generated from $x_2=e^{\frac{2 \pi i}{3}}3^{\frac{1}{3}}$ over the rationals, so is the answer $Q(e^{\frac{2 \pi i}{3}}3^{\frac{1}{3}})$ correct?

---

(b) Again, the roots are the 5 complex roots of unity, all of which can be generated by the root $x_1=e^{\frac{2 \pi i}{5}}$. So would the correct answer now be $Q(e^{\frac{2 \pi i}{5}})$

Comment: Splitting fields over which ground field?

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg The question doesn't specify, perhaps there is an obvious choice? Most of the relevant section is concerned with extensions over the rationals, so my safe assumption is the rationals.

Comment: Also, be very careful with writing a negative number to the power of a fractional exponent. That is an ill-defined expression and that probably caused part of the problem here. Cf. https://math.stackexchange.com/q/317528/96384

Comment: Craig, you should have a look first at what Mathematica means by [$(-3)^{1/3}$](https://tinyurl.com/yahf7fah).

Comment: Thanks, let me rewrite the roots through euler's formula, which is what mathematica means, and edit this question.

Comment: When you do that, you will basically use the $n$th roots of unity. A primitive root of unity is any root $\omega$ that can generate all the others by taking successive powers $\omega^m$. The roots are given by $\exp (2ik\pi/n)$ with $0\le k<n$, and you can prove that the primitive ones are such that $gcd(k,n)=1$.

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut I think I did that, does it look better?

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut Nice! I'll clarify that part.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1597326/degree-of-the-splitting-field-of-x3-5-over-mathbbq

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hints**:

- A real number has $3$ cube roots in $\mathbf C$. One is the standard real cube root, he other two are this real cube root, multiplied by one of the complex cube roots of unity.
- For $x^5-1$,  solve it in the form $\mathrm e^{i\theta}$.

Comment: That does not address the (correct) remark from the OP that the cube root of a negative number is "usually" (and at least in high school) defined to be a real negative number. That's a quirk of Mathematica.

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut: I only gave hints for the implicit questions in the title.

Comment: Correct. ${}{}{}$

Comment: @Bernard Thanks for the hint, I edited my question to re-write the roots as n-th roots of unity, hope I'm getting warmer.